# How to get the actual desktop screen resolution in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot, screen-resolution

I am developing a kinect application using WPF. Now I need to get the actual desktop screen resolution so that I can scale the area to take screenshot for any laptops. I have tried PrimaryScreenWidth, PrimaryScreenHeight, FullScreenHeight, and all that, but none of them give me the ACTUAL resolution. For example, if I have 1920*1080, those above fields will give me some other values.

I was wondering how to get the actual desktop screen resolution from C# WPF?

Answer (score 6):

Just use this:

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

or this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Comment: This returns the screen size independent of the actual resolution.